# How to add data to ObservableCollection with a DatePicker and a TextBox

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, datepicker

Hello i want to add the data from this:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.338,0.312" />
<TextBox x:Name="titleTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,263,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Titre" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
```

in my:

```
ObservableCollection<Rdv>
```

this is my class Rdv:

```
class Rdv
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Rdv(string title, string subject, DateTime date)
    {
        Title = title;
        Subject = subject;
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to proceed. i need to bind Datepicker and Textbox ? how to take off data from these items and create a new ObservableCollection with this data.

Thanks for reading this, hope i didn't make mistake on sentences and thanks for any help.

Comment: Your question is too vague. We have no idea what precisely you try to do in your GUI. Please add more details to your question. How/where do you use the ObservableCollection<Rdv> in your XAML GUI? Where does the DatePicker come into the picture? (like, what is the relationship between the collection and the DatePicker; is it part of an item template?)

Comment: @elgonzo I'd guess he just wants to bind the properties of those controls to viewmodel properties, and add a button to execute a Command that creates a new `Rdv` with the current values. I'd recommend a Click event instead of a Command, just to keep it simple.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, since he has a collection of Rdv objects, it points toward him using something like an ItemsContol and binds to items as part of an itemtemplate. Or perhaps he tries to bind to the selected item only. Or perhaps he has a completely different idea i currently can't think of. Only he himself can tell us... :)

Comment: Yes, I have divided my MainView in three part, left for value to send and button, middle for display all Rdv and right for all information from aspecific Rdv. I use MVVLight and a dataContext. I want to send my data from Datepicker and Textbox when I click on my button, but i don't know how to write my function click_event ( AddRdv() ).
I already did the other things, i just need need help for create a new Rdv for each click on my button

Comment: I do not explain well so I can send all my MainViewModel.cs, XAML and MainPage.xaml.cs if it's not clear for you but I thinks Ed plunkett understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to do this :

```
 public void AddRdv()
    {
        _rdv.Add(new Rdv() {Title = titleTextBox.Text, Subject = subjectTextBox.Text, Date = dateTextBlock.date});
    }
```

But the name titleTextBox, subjectTextBox and dateTextBlock doesn't exist in the context. I use a Datacontext maybe it's because of that.

```
public ObservableCollection<Rdv> Rdv
    {
        get { return _rdv; }
        set
        {
            _rdv = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Rdv _selectedRdv;

    public Rdv SelectedRdv
    {
        get { return _selectedRdv; }
        set
        {
            _selectedRdv = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Rdv = new ObservableCollection<Rdv>()
        {

            new Rdv("Exemple", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", new DateTime(2009, 8, 8)),

        };

        //SelectedRdv = Rdv[0];
    }

    public void AddRdv()
    {
        _rdv.Add(new Rdv() {Title = titleTextBox.Text, Subject = subjectTextBox.Text, Date = dateTextBlock.date});
    }

    public void DeleteSelectedRdv()
    {
        Rdv.Remove(SelectedRdv);
        SelectedRdv = null;
    }
}
```

}